# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-nx}x^n$ converges uniformly for $0 \leq x \leq 10$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Show $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-nx}x^n$ converges
>   uniformly for $0 \leq x \leq 10$.
>
> Hint: Find the maximum of $xe^{-x}$ on the interval.

I was able to find the maximum at $x=1$ which is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e}$. I think I can use the Weierstrass M test for this.

That is, I need to construct a sequence of positive numbers $M_1, M_2, ...$ s.t. $|e^{-kx}x^k| \leq M_k, \forall x \in [0,10]$

and

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n \lt \infty$.

Now the bit I am struggling with is coming up with a sequence of $M$'s s.t. their sum is convergent.

I also see that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e} \lt 1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e^n}$ converges to $0$. But I am struggling with using this fact to constructing the $M$'s.

I would love to have some hints please.

Thank you.

Comment: $M_k = e^{-k}$.

Comment: I just realized this 5s before seeing your comment. I felt so stupid. But thank you!